# how to skip access token validation automatic in loopback

Tags: authentication, access-token, strongloop, loopback

I have two User models (A and B) and two accesstoken models, the original and a custom (base: "AccessToken"),
I managed to make that the tokens of each User model be saved in each table (mysql).

But the problem in this moment is that loopback validates the accesstoken only in a model (table), and I want it validates in the two models (tables).

I am trying to do the first validation by myself before loopback validates in the default model (table), but I dont know how to skip access token validation automatic if  I find that the accesstoken is correct in my first validation.

Any idea about it?

server/server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

 const CustomAccessToken = app.models.CustomAccessToken;

 CustomAccessToken.resolve(req.headers.authorization, function(err, token){
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
     }else{
        console.log(token, "Correct!");
        // Skip default accesstoken valitation
     }
     return next();
  });
```

});

Comment: I already solved it.

Comment: app.use(function(req, res, next) {

   const adminaccesstoken = app.models.adminaccesstoken;
   var currentToken = req.headers.authorization;

   if (typeof currentToken != 'undefined') {

      adminaccesstoken.resolve(currentToken, function(err, cToken){
         
         if(err){
            return next(err);
         }
         
         if (typeof cToken != 'undefined') {
            req.accessToken = cToken;
         }
         
         return next();
      
      });

   } else {
      return next();
   }

});

Comment: You should add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  
  const adminaccesstoken = app.models.adminaccesstoken; 
  var currentToken = req.headers.authorization; 

  if (typeof currentToken != 'undefined') { 
     
     adminaccesstoken.resolve(currentToken, function(err, cToken){ 
        if(err){ return next(err); } 
        if (typeof cToken != 'undefined') { 
          req.accessToken = cToken; 
        } 
        return next(); 
     });
 
   } else { return next(); } 

});
```